How to ensure insertions only accept values defined in Enum?
I am trying to create a simple payment records app, which stores the amount and payment type.
For payment type I have 'cash' and 'credit', which are defined in Mode:
from enum import Enum

class Mode(Enum):
    cash: str
    upi: str

Then, I am defining the table to created with its field as:
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Float, Enum
from utils.database import Base
from utils.paytype import Mode


class Records(Base):
    __tablename__ = "records"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    amount = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    payment_type = Column(Enum(Mode), nullable=False)

When I try to add an entry to the table, I can provide any string as an input for payment_type, which was not the idea. How do I ensure that the entries only accept one of the two defined?

Your enum definition is incorrect -- it's using type hints, which don't actually create any members.  What you need is:
class Mode(Enum):
    cash = "cash"
    upi = "upi"

To make it usable by sqlite, add the adapter method to your enum:
class Mode(Enum):
    #
    cash = "cash"
    upi = "upi"
    #
    def __conform__(self, protocol):
        if protocol is sqlite3.PrepareProtocol:
            return self.name

If you have several enums to be used by sqlite, create your own base class and use that:
import enum
import sqlite

class SqliteEnum(enum.Enum):
    def __conform__(self, protocol):
        if protocol is sqlite3.PrepareProtocol:
            return self.name

class Mode(SqliteEnum):
    cash = "cash"
    upi = "upi"


thank you for providing the correct way. Unfortunately, not able to upvote the answer, due to lack of reputation.!

You actually cannot. There is no Enum type in sqlite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html
What you can do is use pydantic to check input data and eventually raise a ValidationError
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Float, String
from pydantic import BaseModel
from utils.database import Base
from typing import Literal

class Records(Base):
    __tablename__ = "records"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    amount = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    payment_type = Column(String, nullable=False)

class RecordCreate(BaseModel):
    amount: float
    payment_type: Literal["cash", "credit"]

This way
record = RecordCreate(amount=3.14, payment_type="credit") # this is OK
record = RecordCreate(amount=3.14, payment_type="foo")    # this raises a ValidationError

Then you should send to the db the RecordCreate object serialized, i.e.
**record.model_dump()  # with Pydantic v2
**record.dict()        # with Pydantic v1

and use Records to read data from the DB.

Thanks for the advice. Is there a way to do what I wanted to do in mysql or postgres?

Yes there is https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum
